AudioContext suspended when the music changes
Title: AudioContext enters suspended state during track transitions in Web Audio API
Body:
Hello, I'm developing a music player application using the Web Audio API with React, and I've encountered an issue where the AudioContext frequently enters a suspended state, interrupting playback. This happens during automatic track switching.
Here's a brief overview of my implementation:
Initialization of AudioContext:
const [audioContext, setAudioContext] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!audioContext) {
        const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        setAudioContext(context);
    }
}, [audioContext]);

Playing a track:
const play = () => {
    if (audioContext && audioBuffer && !isPlaying) {
        const sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
        sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer;
        sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
        gainNode.gain.value = volume / 100;
        sourceNode.start(0, position);
        setSource(sourceNode);
        setIsPlaying(true);
    }
};

Switching to next track at the end:
const playNextTrack = useCallback(() => {
    setAudioBuffer(null);
    setAudioContext(null);
    setPosition(0);
    setTotalPausedTime(0);
    setCurrentTrackIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % musics.musicInfo.length);
    setIsPlaying(true);
}, [musics.musicInfo.length]);

const updatePosition = useCallback(() => {
    const update = async () => {
        if (!isPlaying || !source || !audioContext) return;

        const currentTime = audioContext.currentTime - totalPausedTime;
        setPosition(Math.floor(currentTime));

        if (currentTime >= (audioBuffer?.duration)) {
            playNextTrack();
        }
    };

    update();
}, [totalPausedTime, audioBuffer?.duration, audioContext, isPlaying, playNextTrack, source]);

The playNextTrack function works when the user clicks on the button, but when it's called at the end of the track, the context passes into suspended...
I tried to restart the context, it works but requires user interaction, which is not my objective:
if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
    try {
        await audioContext.resume();
        console.log('AudioContext resumed');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error resuming AudioContext:', error);
    }
}

I would like once the user starts reading, the change between songs is done automatically.
If you need any clarification, do not hesitate to ask. Thank you very much in advance!

If I understand your code correctly it creates a new AudioContext each time a new track is played. It's not necessary to do that. You can keep using the existing AudioContext that is already running.
